# Can't pass arguments to thread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2012

Okay I am trying to make a thread in c++ that runs the function `storePose();` that function takes nine parameters as doubles. Every time I try to create the thread it complains about the parameters. I will post my code below. I have not a clue why this wont work. Thanks in advanced

**CODE:**

```
std::thread t(storePose,x_position, y_position, z_position, azimuth, att_pitch, att_roll, yaw, cam_pitch, cam_roll);
    t.detach();
```

**ERROR GIVEN:**

```
    12  IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (<unknown-type>, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: _'Intellisense'_ what? Would you be so kind to specify your actual IDE at least then please!

Comment: Sorry its Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Visual C++ (2012) doesn't have support for variadic templates. They have something called *faux variadics* that stamp out overloads via macros. The problem is that there is a limit to the number of arguments you can pass to a variadic template and by default that limit is 5. You can adjust the limit by defining `_VARIADIC_MAX` to be a larger number (e.g. for a limit of 10 set `/D_VARIADIC_MAX=10`)

See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) and [this](http://blog.ashodnakashian.com/2012/09/faux-variadics-and-vs2012).

Comment: thank you, that could help me, where exactly do i put that to set it? Sorry im newer to this type of programming

Comment: Right click on your project in Solution Explorer. Select Properties... and naviagete to C/C++ -> Preprocessor and set add _VARIADIC_MAX=10 to "Preprocessor Definitions". Make sure you do that for all the configurations of the project (debug, release, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so so much. I have been messing with this for hours and that is a bit too high level for me to have gotten! Thank you again so much, and I'm not to sure why it got down voted twice if I was able to get a good answer! THANK YOU!

Comment: If you don't mind looking at my new [Question HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388068/boostthread-thread-not-accepting-arguments) I have this error again after switching to the Boost threads.

Answer (score -1):

Too many arguments, put them in a struct and give the struct to the thread function and deal with the args in the struct.

Comment: i will try this, but i did try to put the arguments in a vector and just overloaded the funciton and it still gave me an error that was very similar

Comment: Does the signature of the storePos function match the given arguments?

Comment: yes the funciton is declared in my header as this: `void storePose(double lat, double lon, double alt, double attYaw, double attPitch, double attRoll, double camYaw, double camPitch, double camRoll);`

Comment: and it was `void storePose(vector<double> params);` when i tried that